# Parser error Couldn't parse params file - Trying to load YAML file

Tags: ros2, gazebo-simu, urdf

I have been searching for a solution to my problem but am unable to find any solutions for my problem that are also using Python. I am trying to run Universal Robot's UR10e in gazebo and control it using ROS2_control.

I am running ROS2 Iron and Gazebo 11.

This is the error I continue to get:

```
gazebo-1] [ERROR] [1689265614.750035709] [gazebo_ros2_control]: parser error Couldn't parse params file: '--params-file $(find sim)/Controller_config.yaml'. 
Error: Error opening YAML file, at ./src/parser.c:271, at ./src/rcl/arguments.c:406
```

My Setup.py already puts the YAML file into my install folder. I am trying to run my YAML file through my URDF rather than my launch file. My launch file launches the URDF and Gazebo together

Here is a snippet of my Setup.py:

```
setup(
    name=package_name,
    version='0.0.0',
    packages=find_packages(exclude=['test']),
    data_files=[
        ('share/ament_index/resource_index/packages',
            ['resource/' + package_name]),
        ('share/' + package_name, ['package.xml', 'launch/simulation.launch.py']),
        ('share/' + package_name, ['package.xml', 'description/urdf/ur10e.urdf']),
        ('share/' + package_name, ['package.xml', 'description/urdf/config/Controller_config.yaml']),
    ],
```

Here is my YAML file I am trying to load:

```
controller_manager:
  ros_parameters:
    update_rate: 100 #Hz

    joint_trajectory_controller:
      type: joint_trajectory_controller/JointTrajectoryController  

    joint_state_broadcaster:
      type: joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster

joint_trajectory_controller:  
  ros_parameters:
    joints:
- base_joint
  - shoulder_pan_joint
  - shoulder_lift_joint
  - elbow_joint
  - wrist_1_joint
  - wrist_2_joint
  - wrist_3_joint
interface_name:
  - position
state_interfaces:
  - position
  - velocity
```

Here is the Plugin I am using in my URDF to load the YAML:

```
<gazebo>
  <plugin filename="libgazebo_ros2_control.so" name="gazebo_ros2_control">
    <parameters>$(find sim)/Controller_config.yaml</parameters>
  </plugin>
</gazebo>
```

Comment: Please let me know if any more information is needed, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I came across with the similar error message. I figure out that I should use spaces instead of tab indentaion in the yaml file. Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

I also have that issue. "parser error Couldn't parse params file: ", I think joint_trajectory_controller is the problem. try to add "" to param values.